# Trouble deploying Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I am trying to deploy my first Ruby on Rails app to shared server. The application is really just a proof of concept, I wanted to show to a few people so I am not worried about traffic.

Anyway, I am having trouble with 2 gems nokogiri and sqlite3. I am trying to deploy from a windows 7 machine to a Linux distro.

When I try an run bundle install - I get an error, probably because of lack of admin rights.

> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>   (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

If I use bundle package and bundle install --deployment

> rake aborted! no such file to load -- sqlite3

If I use IRB and require "sqlite3" it works.
==> return true

I am at a loss, what do I do next?

Comment: Have you looked in your host's help section to see if they have documentation on setting rails up with bundler?

Comment: There documentation is sparse, it does not mention bundler.

Comment: Have you tried doing `bundle exec install`?

Comment: If it's just a concept app why not just push it up to [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)?

Answer (score -1):

With ubuntu it's

```
  sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

You've got the ruby libraries, but you still need the sqlite3 library.
Just doing this i think your problem is solved . If it still problem comes then i you should try to install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev libraries .

```
 sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

Thanks

Comment: Since it is a shared server I do not have the ability to update the install.